# CVE-2015-3225 rack and passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

Following [CVE-2015-3225](https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_source=digest&utm_medium=email#!topic/rubyonrails-security/gcUbICUmKMc), I want to update the rack version of some apps that are hosted via passenger in production. However, I am not sure what the relationship is between passenger and rack. Do I need to update the version of rack passenger is using, or the rack version specified in each apps Gemfile.lock, or should I being updating both?

I think the answer is the latter (both) but if I can fix the vulnerability just by updating the rack version passenger is using, then that is a lot less work.

It was this [google forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phusion-passenger/w2g66bsRoVw) post that made me think passenger was defining the rack version, but reading it again I don't think that's the case.

Comment: The more I look into this, the more I'm sure updating each app is the only way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `rack` version is defined in the application. Each application can have its own `rack` version and Passenger will load it.

Therefore, what you want to upgrade is the `rack` version your application is currently using.